# htaccess file with multiple RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess

Is this correct?

I tried navigating to `www.alltheoptions.co.uk` but it didn't redirect to the `https://` version

```
# Redirect Browser to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.alltheoptions\.co.uk$ [NC] [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\alltheoptions\.co.uk$ [NC] [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\http://alltheoptions\.co.uk$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.alltheoptions\.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]


# Block Unwanted User Agents - Spiders/Bots
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase ^User-Agent$ .*(bot1|bot2|bot3|bot4|bot5|bot6|) HTTP_SAFE_BADBOT
SetEnvIfNoCase ^User-Agent$ .*(bot1|bot2|bot3|bot4|bot5|bot6|) HTTP_SAFE_BADBOT
Deny from env=HTTP_SAFE_BADBOT
</ifModule>

# Security - name to access htaccess file
AccessFileName ht.access
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change first rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.alltheoptions\.co\.uk$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.alltheoptions\.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I think the main thing to remember is when referencing a `.co.uk` URL, the `\ (backslash)` has to be present before every `. (dot)`